# Is there a car-rental scheme that works worldwide?

Tags: car-rentals, insurance, worldwide

Personally, I find it quite an annoyance to deal with car rental. I always end up singing a two sided paper with small print, simply because I am to tired to bother. That this is naive approach was proven, when I was the receiving party in a rear-end accident. ALthoug it was clear from the start, I wasn't liable rental agency still deemed it appropriate to take 500 Euro from my Credit Card. I heard from other that this common practice and you need to explicitly take insurance against this. Since, this accident I always ask, but in many cases you still remain liable for at least 500 Euro (sometimes even 1200 Euro) in case of an accident. In the end you can get your money back, but I learned from experience that this can take up to two years.

With this in mind and my (naive) desire to sign only if I know the consequences I am wondering if there isn't a car-sharing or rental scheme that works globally with one contract and covers all insurances in a similar manner? Also with a clear picture on the amount you are liable for in case of damage.

Comment: Would you not be worth taking out additional insurance yourself, to cover you for the excess no matter who you rent from?

Comment: @gagravarr I would love to, but I have been searching for quite a while and it seems that those insurances are more common in us/uk then where I live.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking for. Driving regulations, insurance, etc. vary worldwide, according to local customs and laws. So I very much doubt there will be a universal scheme that allows you to drive anywhere without the initial agreement being 100s of pages. What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

zipcar membership is world wide

Car2go is regional, North American customers have access to cars in USA and Canada. Don'
t know what the rules are for europe

Comment: Zip Car membership has a 750 USD charge for an accident. Not sure if the OP wanted to avoid this or not.

Comment: @AdityaSomani $750 if you are at fault, which is roughly the same as a rental car company. If you got rear-ended and got the other drivers details you should be ok. IIRC you can buy extra zipcar insurance